# crosstab variables of tibble and make the output readable

Tags: r, tidyverse, crosstab

I have to cross tabulate variables of tibble. I used `table()` for it, but the output is not easily readable.

Is there a way to format the output to make it more easily readable.

Thanks

```
library(tidyverse)

# random arrays of 0 and 1
a <- sample(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), replace = TRUE, size = 100)
b <- sample(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), replace = TRUE, size = 100)

tbl <- tibble(a, b)

cross_tab <- table(tbl$a, tbl$b)

cross_tab
```

Comment: How about the following;
`colnames(cross_tab) <- paste("a = ", colnames(cross_tab), sep = ""); rownames(cross_tab) <- paste("b = ", rownames(cross_tab), sep = "")
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `expss` for these kinds of tables:

```
library(expss)
cro(tbl$a,tbl$b) %>% htmlTable()
```

You can precede the command above with the expss command `apply_labels` to format the variable and value names. See the documentation for details.